# data factory - dataflow to return distinct rows

Tags: azure-data-factory

```
field1  field2      field3
name1   surname1    address1
name1   surename1   address1
name1   surename1   address1
name2   surename2   address2
name2   surename2   address2
name2   surename2   address2
...
```

In my select activity, it returns in data preview several fields.
There are duplicates and I would like to return distict rows.
After the select activity I have placed an aggregate activity.
Inside this aggregate activity the screenshot below

How is this done please?

Comment: Hi, the screenshot is not available, can you please edit and provide the screenshot of the aggregate activity settings which you used?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the column pattern in the aggregate transformation to remove duplicate rows from the source.

**Source:**

[image]

**Aggregate transformation:**

[image]

Column that matches: `name != 'field1' && name!= 'field2' && name!= 'field3'`

[image]

**Aggregate output:**

[image]

Comment: Hi, when I tried your example I received the error: the output field2 is duplicated in 2 places... so I tried like name == field1 && name == field2... and this worked but I do not see how